# Getting rid of unwanted commits

Tags: git, github

My branch was behind master, I used `git pull origin master` and now I have 44 commits not mine and I don't want to push them along with my changes.
How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: You need to `rebase` _your_ local `master` branch onto the remote `master` - or `merge` the incoming commits into your local `master` _then_ do `git push`.

Comment: Also, you **definitely do _not_** want to simply "get rid" of those commits - that's other people's work!

Comment: @Dai Yeah by getting rid of meant going back to state where I don't have those commits. Can you clarify? 
Do I go to my branch and do `git rebase master`?

Comment: Push where? You can't push your changes to master without them.

Comment: Only do `git rebase` if you know what it actually means - the same goes for all command-line commands, honestly (y'know... `rm / -rf`...). You should read the Git Book: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2 - or at least watch a video that explains how `rebase` and `merge` works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CRlGDDprdOQ

Answer (score 1):

a. Inspect the state of your repository

open a graphical viewer to inspect the history of your repository, or from a terminal run:

```
git log --graph --oneline
```

b. spot the state (the commit) you want to return to.

The quickest way is: if the commit you want to return to is still in your history, from the view above, copy the sha of this target commit.

The most deterministic way is: run `git reflog master`, and see where your `master` branch was before you ran `git pull`.

Copy the sha of the commit you want to return to, and run `git reset --hard <sha>`.
If you have uncommitted modifications in your repo, you probably want to run `git stash` before that.